# Efficient searching over multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I have `DataFrame` like that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {
        'name': 'Alexandra',
        'surname': 'Johnson',
        'age': 5
    },
    {
        'name': 'Roland',
        'surname': 'Hawking',
        'age': 3
    }
])
```

To find rows matching a certain condition I use combination of conditions:

```
df[((df['name']=='Roland') | (df['surname']=='Johnson')) & (df['age'] > 4)]
```

returning

```
        name  surname  age
0  Alexandra  Johnson    5
```

However, this does not scale well for several hundred thousand rows. To speed up search over a column I used to index that column:

```
indexed = df.set_index('name')
indexed[indexed.index == 'Roland']
```

For multiple columns I can use `MultiIndex`, however I don't know how can I use combination of boolean conditions with multiple indexes. Can you advice?

Comment: i wonder if stacking into a single series then using `isin` would be quicker, interesting question.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this is what u r referring to, so i'll take a stab at it:

set name and surname as the index

```
df = df.set_index(['name','surname'])
```

filter for alexandra and johnson - pass it in as a tuple

```
df.loc[('Alexandra', 'Johnson')]

    age    5
Name: (Alexandra, Johnson), dtype: int64
```

U will get much faster speeds if u use iloc, but that requires u to know the specific indexes. but yeah, with multiindex, u pass a tuple of the indexes, if it is three columns, then u will have three elements in ur tuple

Comment: Ok, this implements conjunction (logical and) of conditions. How do you implement an alternative (logical or) and combination of conjuction with alternative?

Comment: the [query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) method should be significantly faster for larger datasets. i dont think you can do the 'or' thing with multiindexes